# How to determine a function from data $2$-dimensional graph

Tags: interpolation

I assume it is possible. Let us say I have $3$ years worth of water amount of rain collected everyday.

A $2$-dimensional graph has been created from the data and there is pattern every year. How do I come out with a function?

Comment: I believe you are looking for a [function interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). In particular, [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) is the simplest way instance of interpolation of a function of $2$ variables.

Comment: This sounds like a time series modeling exercise on data with seasonality. I would start by reading up on seasonality and how to measure it and model it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality. There are also dozens of textbooks on this topic.